# How to set key in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want my result of json is like this :

```
[{
    "api_code": "111402",
    "nama_proyek": "PLTA LAU GUNUNG 2x7.5 MW",
    "dvo": "INFRA 2",
    "project_progress_plan": "96.644",
    "id": "7187",
    "rencana": [
      "Segera Dibuatkan  Addendum  waktu & Addendum Kontrak ",
      "Segera dibuatkan Addendum Kontrak ke 5"
    ],
    "target": "09/20/2019",
    "status": "open",
    "realisasi": "76.53",
    "project_progress_real": "93.04",
    "progress_deviasi": "-20.114",
    "end_date": "09-09-2019",
    "start_date": "22-12-2015"
  },
{
    "api_code": "218007",
    "nama_proyek": "Pembangunan Simpang Susun Sentul Selatan",
    "dvo": "INFRA 1",
    "project_progress_plan": "81.69",
    "id": "7301",
    "rencana": [
      "Dengan adanya  addendum  1 maka masa pelaksanaan sampai dengan  bulan  Maret 2020  dengan revisi progres Renacana 31.992 % Realiasasi 34.564 %  deviasi + 2.572 "
    ],
    "target": "09/09/2019",
    "status": "open",
    "realisasi": "35.556",
    "project_progress_real": "44.98",
    "progress_deviasi": "-46.134",
    "end_date": "27-10-2019",
    "start_date": "29-01-2019"
  }],
```

but my result of json is like this if I delete in my code the key the value looping just once:

```
"111402": {
    "api_code": "111402",
    "nama_proyek": "PLTA LAU GUNUNG 2x7.5 MW",
    "dvo": "INFRA 2",
    "project_progress_plan": "96.644",
    "id": "7187",
    "rencana": [
      "Segera Dibuatkan  Addendum  waktu & Addendum Kontrak ",
      "Segera dibuatkan Addendum Kontrak ke 5"
    ],
    "target": "09/20/2019",
    "status": "open",
    "realisasi": "76.53",
    "project_progress_real": "93.04",
    "progress_deviasi": "-20.114",
    "end_date": "09-09-2019",
    "start_date": "22-12-2015"
  },
  "218007": {
    "api_code": "218007",
    "nama_proyek": "Pembangunan Simpang Susun Sentul Selatan",
    "dvo": "INFRA 1",
    "project_progress_plan": "81.69",
    "id": "7301",
    "rencana": [
      "Dengan adanya  addendum  1 maka masa pelaksanaan sampai dengan  bulan  Maret 2020  dengan revisi progres Renacana 31.992 % Realiasasi 34.564 %  deviasi + 2.572 "
    ],
    "target": "09/09/2019",
    "status": "open",
    "realisasi": "35.556",
    "project_progress_real": "44.98",
    "progress_deviasi": "-46.134",
    "end_date": "27-10-2019",
    "start_date": "29-01-2019"
  },
```

and this is my code, the code is inner join from 3 table and one "proyek" have many "rencana", in this case i have done to grouping it by "api_code" but the result is not same with my expect:

```
$proyek = $this->db->query("SELECT proyek.api_code, proyek.nama_proyek, proyek.dvo,
    pp_proyek.project_progress_plan, proyek.id, proyek_kritis_rencana.rencana, 
    proyek_kritis_rencana.target, proyek_kritis_rencana.status, 
    proyek.realisasi, proyek.project_progress_real, proyek.progress_deviasi, 
    pp_proyek.end_date, pp_proyek.start_date FROM proyek 
    INNER JOIN pp_proyek ON pp_proyek.code = proyek.api_code 
    INNER JOIN proyek_kritis_rencana ON proyek_kritis_rencana.proyek = proyek.id")->result_array();



$last = array();
foreach($proyek as $row){
    $id = $row['api_code'];
        if(isset($last[$id])){
            $last[$id]['rencana'][] = $row['rencana'];
        }else{
            $row['rencana'] = array($row['rencana']);
            $last[$id] = $row;
        }
}
```

Comment: What you "want" is not valid JSON. Take a look at the bracket hierarchy...

Comment: sorry my bad, I made a mistake while typing

Comment: Thanks, better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `array_values()` on your `$last` array, which will remove the ID keys

```
$last = array(
    "111402" => array(
        "api_code" => "111402",
        "nama_proyek" => "PLTA LAU GUNUNG 2x7.5 MW",
        "dvo" => "INFRA 2",
    )
    , "218007" => array(
        "api_code" => "218007",
        "nama_proyek" => "Pembangunan Simpang Susun Sentul Selatan",
        "dvo" => "INFRA 1",     
    )
 );

 echo json_encode($last);

 $last = array_values($last); // remove keys
 echo json_encode($last);
```

First output :

```
{"111402":{
    "api_code":"111402",
    "nama_proyek":"PLTA LAU GUNUNG 2x7.5 MW",
    "dvo":"INFRA 2"
},"218007":{
    "api_code":"218007",
    "nama_proyek":"Pembangunan Simpang Susun Sentul Selatan",
    "dvo":"INFRA 1"}
}
```

Second output (simple array, no more ID keys) :

```
[{
    "api_code":"111402",
    "nama_proyek":"PLTA LAU GUNUNG 2x7.5 MW",
    "dvo":"INFRA 2"
 },{
    "api_code":"218007",
    "nama_proyek":"Pembangunan Simpang Susun Sentul Selatan",
    "dvo":"INFRA 1"
}]
```

Comment: give me example, please. I didn't get it